# trying to figure out a good database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

OK here is my problem I am trying to design a database for a class project. I am having a difficult time with figuring out how to relate one table to another. In this instance i am trying to have a Primary key that can represent several different items. Like a single PizzaOrderID representing both a meat lovers, veggie lovers, and a cheese pizza. all with different quantities of pizzas. Can someone please help me out with how I might be able to set up this design?

Edit:

Third Normal Form

### Customer

Customer ID → Primary Key

first name last name street address Apartment City State Zip Code Home phone mobile phone Other phone

### Doughnut

Doughnut ID → Primary Key

Name Description

### Doughnut Order

Doughnut Order ID → Primary Key

Doughnut ID → Foreign Key

Quantity Unit Price

### Order Sales

Order → Primary Key

Doughnut Order ID → Foreign Key

ok this what i had as my third normal form as you can see the exact item i am dealing with is doughnuts i am guessing i need to adjust this form

Comment: You need an ORDER table and a MENU table. And then connect both with a ORDER_MENU table

Comment: True.  also the ORDER_MENU table will have two columns, call them ORDER_ID and MENU_ID that are both foreign keys.  Taken together they are the primary key of ORDER_MENU.

Comment: ok i have a pizza table with pizzaid as my primary and i have an order table with orderid as my primary now i also have a pizzaorder table with a foreign key of my pizzaid so should i set a primary key as pizzaorderid even though when it links the pizza id it will not accept the same pizzaorderid number

Comment: Third Normal Form
    Customer
    Customer ID → Primary Key
    first name
    last name
    street address
    Apartment
    City
    State
    Zip Code
    Home phone
    mobile phone
    Other phone
    Doughnut
    Doughnut ID → Primary Key
    Name
    Description
    Doughnut Order
    Doughnut Order ID → Primary Key
    Doughnut ID → Foreign Key
    Quantity
    Unit Price
    Order Sales Order → Primary Key
Doughnut Order ID → Foreign Key
ok this what i had as my third normal form as you can see the exact item i am dealing with is doughnuts i am guessing i need to adjust this form

Comment: please put that in an [edit] to question not down here

Comment: why do you have an order table and a pizzaorder table as per the 3rd comment?

Comment: also, as presumably you have a server, showing table design via `show create table myTableName` output for each is more readable than human gobblygook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning. You have a table representing meals, which you apparently call **pizza** and this table has a primary key **pizza_id**. (I use _ for readability). Such meal can be ordered at a restaurant table, by putting an **order** stored in another table with primary key **order_id**.

So far so good. Now the order can be for one pizza, two, or more of them. Moreover the order can contain more pizzas of the same kind! Apparently your design needs to cover for this and the solution is N:M (many to many) relation.

This is done in the third table called **orderitem** with a **compound primary key** (composed from two columns) **pizza_id** and **order_id**. These two are simultaneously foreign keys referring to their respective tables. As additional column can be put amount of the meals, which are of the same kind.